# How to wrap a C style array in an Elegant Object?

Tags: c++, oop, boost, smart-pointers, c++98

I'm Working in C++98 with a library that uses C style arrays.

I'd like to hide all that and simply interact with it via declarative code. 
I'm looking for something like this pseudocode.
Smart pointers are a challenge at the mo.

I can use boost smart pointers from boost 1.61 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

```
class ElegantArray
{
  private:
    char* array;  // <<<==== should be a unique or auto ptr?
    int size;
    std::string aString;

  public:

    ElegantArray(char* array_, int size_) { // <<<=============should require a smart pointer
      array = array_;
      size = size_;    //<<<===constructor leaves aString nil which requires nil checks =(
    }

    ElegantArray(std::string aString_) {
      aString = aString_;   // <<<===constructor leaves array and size nil which requires nil checks =(
    }

  std::string string() {
    int i;  //put inside for loop?
    std::string strng = "";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { strng = strng + array[i]; }
    return strng;
  }

  //How & What do i return here unique or auto ptr?
  char* cArrayPointer() {
    int n = aString.length();
    char charArray[n+1];
    strcpy(charArray, aString.c_str());
    return charArray;  // <<<==================should return a smart pointer
  }    
}
```

Call site would be something like

```
ElegantArray elegantArray(smartPointerToCArray, arraySize);
std::string aString = elegantArray.string();
```

AND

```
ElegantArray elegantArray("Falalalala");
SmartPointerToCArray smartPointerToCArray = elegantArray.cArrayPointer();
```

Please advise.

Comment: C++ isn't declarative, so you are using the wrong language?

Comment: My advice would be to upgrade to C++11 or newer and use `std::array`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this class? Is it supposed to own the array that `array` points to, i.e. should it `free` the array when the class instance is destroyed? Can the `char` array provided to the constructor be copied or does it have to store a pointer to the original? What is the purpose of the `std::string` member? Do you intend this to be something like a `std::variant` or `std::string_view`? From what I can tell the whole class should just be replaced by `std::string` from the start.

Comment: Better than "pseudocode" would be a list of requirements. What are the goals for this class? What functionality does this class require? What makes this class different from `std::string`, `std::vector`, and/or `boost::array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're working with APIs that deal with `char *` and either; need to interface with other APIs that deal with `std::string`, or just want to use a nicer representation to work with in your own code. In either case, `std::string` itself is likely to be the ideal solution.

The `std::string` type already supports conversions between the two types trivially; for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_c_string(const char *arr)
{
    printf("arr := '%s'\r\n", arr);
}

void print_std_string(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << "str := '" << str << '\'' << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Get a C-style string
    char *arr = (char *)malloc(strlen("c-style string") + 1);
    memcpy(arr, "c-style string", strlen("c-style string"));
    arr[strlen("c-style string")] = '\0';

    // Get a std::string
    std::string str("standard lib string");

    print_c_string(arr);
    print_std_string(str);

    // Get a std::string from the C-style string
    std::string fromArr(arr);
    print_std_string(fromArr);

    // Get C-style string from std::string
    print_c_string(str.c_str());

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

// output:
// arr := 'c-style string'
// str := 'standard lib string'
// str := 'c-style string'
// arr := 'standard lib string'
```

In terms of lifetime, constructing a `std::string` from a `char *` will copy the data in so the lifetimes aren't coupled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Get a C-style string
    char *arr = (char *)malloc(strlen("c-style string") + 1);
    memcpy(arr, "c-style string", strlen("c-style string"));
    arr[strlen("c-style string")] = '\0';

    {
        std::string str(arr);
        std::cout << "std::string from arr := '" << str << '\'' << std::endl;
        str.clear();
        std::cout << "cleared std::string from arr := '" << str << '\'' << std::endl;
    }

    printf("arr := '%s'\r\n", arr);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

// output:
// std::string from arr := 'c-style string'
// cleared std::string from arr := ''
// arr := 'c-style string'
```

On the other hand, getting a `char *` from a `std::string` will actually give a the pointer to the data of the string so you need to consider how the consumers of the `char *` will treat it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *arr;

    {
        std::string str("standard lib string");

        arr = str.c_str();
        printf("arr := '%s'\r\n", arr);

        // Modifying the data at the char * will affect the string, don't do this.
        //
        // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/
        // > A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.
        ((char *)arr)[1] = '7';
        std::cout << "str := '" << str << '\'' << std::endl;

        // The implication here is that if an API is expecting a char * that it will
        // modify or own then you'll need to copy the data out and manage the lifetime
        // of the copy accordingly.

        // Mutating the string will similarly change the data at the char *.
        for (auto & c: str) c = toupper(c);
        printf("arr := '%s'\r\n", arr);
    }

    // Once the string is gone there's no guarantee about the data at the char *.
    // You'll need to make sure the string outlives the char * or make a copy of the data.

    printf("arr := '%s'\r\n", arr);

    return 0;
}

// output:
// arr := 'standard lib string'
// str := 's7andard lib string'
// arr := 'S7ANDARD LIB STRING'
// arr := ''
```

Comment: "*Modifying the data at the char * will affect the string, don't do this.*": Not only that, it will cause undefined behavior. A non-`const` pointer that can be used to modify the string contents (but not the null-terminator at its end or anything beyond that) can be obtained from `.data()` since C++17 or `&str[0]` since C++11.

Comment: Similarly "*Once the string is gone there's no guarantee about the data at the `char *`.*": Not only are the contents unspecified, dereferencing the pointer at this point at all is undefined behavior.

Comment: wow that's a generous answer. thank you for pointing me in the right direction. i think i need to read more about c strings and std::string.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about c-arrays of `char`. In that case you are looking for `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    typedef std::string ElegantArray;

    char x[] = "Foo";
    const char* y = "Bar";

    ElegantArray a(x);
    ElegantArray b(y);
    ElegantArray c("Baz");
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;

}
```

If you need a c-string use `std::string::c_str()`.